# Update MYSQL Table automatically with php when user updates the other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

Hello
I'll explain to you with an example.

If an admin updates the `admin` table, then some data is automatically added to the `stock` table. And if a client submits a form to the `sales` table, then also some parts of the data update automatically in the `stock` table.

I mean I want some contents of the admin and sales tables in the stock table. I want to do the process with PHP.

Comment: I don't understand your question, please clarify!

Comment: TRIGGERS is the word. Check this URL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use either triggers, as Cybernate mentioned, or stored procedures to combine the two operations.

Triggers - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Stored Procedures - http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedproc.html

If you want to do it in PHP only, simply add the update to the other table within whatever functions you are using.